# Prevent Graph API to send email

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to prevent Graph API from sending emails when events are created? The use case is that the app sends email on its own and would prefer that outlook not send the email

I've tried creating event with `responseRequested`: false. But looks like it is still sending the email.

Answer (score 0):

**Although i haven't tried this out, but i strongly recommend you to try it and see if it works.**
In the request json body, there's a key `attendes`, which is a json array containing a list of all the event attendes. Try sending an empty json for it.
Eg:
In the request body, send this as well

```
  "attendees": [
  ]
```

This will create the required event, but the users won't be emailed.

Comment: Calendly does similar to what I'd like to achieve, it sends out personalised email instead of vendor specific calendar invites. I'd still need to keep the record of who the attendees are though. I think I've a way to work around this. Thanks anyways

Comment: Hi @Sajan Did you find anything to handle this from API level? I need the same functionality.

Comment: Hi @taurus05 If we set attendees to [] then attendees won't be able to join that meeting. My case is that event should be visible on attendee's calendar but email should not be sent to them.

Comment: @PujabaZala Sorry I couldn't find a way to achieve this via api and ended up just sending outlook emails